# How to create a selection screen, where to select an text option the [w] and [a] keys are used to move up and down? (C# and Monogame)

Tags: c#, monogame

I want to be able to select an option from a menu with only vertical movement.
All available options are available to be seen by the player. The currently selected option should be visibly highlighted, or it should be clear in some other manner that the option is selected (for example, making the text color different)

I'm new to Game development and can't find any tutorials on how to create a menu like this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, it's at it simpliest just an array of text strings where you can use an integer that increases/decreases by pressing up/down. You can use that integer to act as an arrow or highlight that focusses on the text.

A rough sample idea:

Initialising:

```
string[] texts = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
int selection = 0;
```

Draw:

```
for (int i = 0; i < texts.length; i++)
{
    draw_text(text[i], 50, 50+20*i)
    if (i == selection)
    {
        text.color = yellow;
    }
}
```

`Draw_text` could be replaced with a `StringBuilder.Write` or similair, but I hope this could get the idea accross.